# NSMangedObject replace at Index

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm still new to `NSMangedObject`s and I'm having trouble replacing objects at a certain index.

```
 for (NSString *file in filelist){

    NSManagedObject *fileEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fileEntity setValue:file forKey:@"filename"];

    NSImage *audioImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"tag_white.png"];
    [fileEntity setValue:audioImage forKey:@"taggedImage"];
    [markedAudioFiles addObject:audioImage];

}
```

As you can see I can easily insert into the managed object just fine.  It displays the files on a table and everything.  However, I want to change some values at a certain index for the `@"taggedImage"` key.

So I tried something like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *fileEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
NSImage *audioImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"tag_green.png"];

[fileEntity replaceValueAtIndex:index inPropertyWithKey:@"taggedImage" withValue:audioImage];
```

The error I get is:

> [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key taggedImage.

I even tried replacing the `fileEntity` declaration above with

```
NSManagedObject *fileEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

but since it's not a new object I figured that's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second block of code `fileEntity` is just a description of an object, it isn't an actual `NSManagedObject` so it won't have the key `taggedImages`.

However, that's not the real reason you're code won't work. THere's a bigger problem in what  I think you're trying to do isn't the way to do it!

If you're trying to update the `taggedImage` property of the `File` object at index *n*, that's not the way to do it. Your first problem is how are the File objects ordered in CoreData - is it by name, is it by created on date, is it by random? You don't know so asking for the item at *n* doesn't make any sense yet!

You need to query your data store and get the items in a specific order (See `NSFetchRequest` and the [Core Data tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/05_Fetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH107-SW1) from Apple.

Once you have your file objects out of core data in the order you want then you can just get the item at index *n*, update it's taggedImage and then save it.

---

PS However, this will get very inefficient with lots of items in core data if you have to get them all each time you only want to update one :)